# How to filter views_edit in user list table?

Tags: wordpress

The following is a screenshot of the users list table in the dashboard. I'd like to customize highlighted part:

[image]

I know how do it in the posts list table using the method explained in this [WordPress Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19418/how-to-add-a-quicklink-to-the-posts-admin-publishedscheduledtrash-menu/52075#52075).

I tried to use filter **`views_edit-user`** but nothing happened. I also tried to Google it but it seems this filter doesn't have documentation or is not really a WordPress filter.

How to customize that admin section using `add_action` or `add_filter`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The hook for that screen is based on `'views_' . $this->screen->id`, so it should be:

```
add_filter( 'views_users', 'modify_views_users_so_15295853' );

function modify_views_users_so_15295853( $views ) 
{
    // Manipulate $views

    return $views;
}
```

The content of `$views` in my system is:

```
Array
(
    [all] => <a href='users.php' class="current">All <span class="count">(7)</span></a>
    [administrator] => <a href='users.php?role=administrator'>Administrator <span class="count">(1)</span></a>
    [editor] => <a href='users.php?role=editor'>Editor <span class="count">(1)</span></a>
    [subscriber] => <a href='users.php?role=subscriber'>Subscriber <span class="count">(5)</span></a>
)
```

Comment: Any tip on rendering the count efficiently?

Comment: $posts = wp_count_posts( 'job_listing' );
$billed_count = $posts->billed;

... having trouble getting selected status to embolden.

Comment: @brasofilo hey man how about custom column in user list table like i have enable and disable status in column. so i want display like enable(5) disable (4)

Comment: @brasofilo, can only a portion of the array be updated? For example `[administrator]` and to return the remainder the array as-is?

Comment: @Motivated, yes, you would do `$views['administrator']="<your_html>"; return $views;`