# How i can add "subsubsub" quick links on wordpress user section

Tags: wordpress

How i can add "subsubsub" quick links on wordpress user section[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLu3z.png)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I didn't find how to add a quick link on user section. but i find the filter for post 

add_filter('views_edit-movies','wp37_update_movies_quicklinks');
function wp37_update_movies_quicklinks($views) {
     return $views;
}

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303126/6832075
It explains exactly what you wanted to achieve